# Time Complexity of Multi level Encryption and Decryption Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, encryption, rsa, time-complexity

In my project I have provided "Encryption and Decryption" through Multi Level algorithms.

I used RSA and 3DES for this. Now I want to calculate its time complexity for performance analysis. I am a little bit confused here. How to exactly calculate it or what's the time complexity for it.

Following is the Algo.

**Helper Class**

```
class Helper{  
 public Cipher dcipher,ecipher;  
 public Helper(String passPhrase){  
    byte[] salt = 
      {  (byte)0xA9, (byte)0x9B, (byte)0xC8, (byte)0x32,  
         (byte)0x56, (byte)0x34, (byte)0xE3, (byte)0x03  
      };  
    int iterationCount = 19;  
    try {    
          KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passPhrase.toCharArray(), salt,                  
                    iterationCount);  
          SecretKey key =                                
              SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES").generateSecret(keySpec);  
          ecipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());  
          dcipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());  
          AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt,
                                       iterationCount);  
          ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);  
          dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);  
    } 
    catch(Exception e){ } 
}  
@SuppressWarnings("unused")  
protected String encrypt(String str){  
        try{  
          byte[] utf8 = str.getBytes("UTF8");  
          byte[] enc = ecipher.doFinal(utf8);  
          return new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(enc);  
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {   } 
        return null;  
}      
// Decrpt password     
//To decrypt the encryted password  
protected String decrypt(String str) {  
  Cipher dcipher = null;  
  try{  
        byte[] salt = {(byte)0xA9, (byte)0x9B, (byte)0xC8, (byte)0x32,(byte)0x56, 
                       (byte)0x34, (byte)0xE3, (byte)0x03};  
        int iterationCount = 19;  
      try{   
        String passPhrase="";  
        KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passPhrase.toCharArray(), salt,
                        iterationCount);  
        SecretKey key = 
              SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES").generateSecret(keySpec);            
        dcipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());  
        // Prepare the parameters to the cipthers   
            AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, 
                               iterationCount);  
        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);  
      }   
  catch (Exception e) { 
            System.out.println("EXCEPTION: InvalidAlgorithmParameterException");  
      }  
      byte[] dec = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(str);  
      // Decrypt  
      byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(dec);  
      // Decode using utf-8  
      return new String(utf8, "UTF8");  
   }  
   catch (BadPaddingException e) {  
   } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {  
   } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {  
   } catch (IOException e){  
}  
return null;  
}
```

**MultilevelEnc Class**

```
public String Encrypt()
{

    try
    {
        KeyPairGenerator kpg=KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        kpg.initialize(512);//initialize key pairs to 512 bits ,you can also take 1024 or 2048 bits
        kp=kpg.genKeyPair();
        PublicKey publi=kp.getPublic();
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publi);
        byte[]src=srci.getBytes();//converting source data into byte array
        cipherData = cipher.doFinal(src);//use this method to finally encrypt data
        srco=new String(cipherData);//converting byte array into string
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
        return srco;
}
public String Decrypt(String cipherdata)
    {
        try
        {

        PrivateKey privatei=kp.getPrivate();//Generating private key
        Cipher cipheri=Cipher.getInstance("RSA");//Intializing 2nd instance of Cipher class
        cipheri.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privatei);//Setting to decrypt_mode
        byte[] cipherDat = cipheri.doFinal(cipherData);//Finally decrypting data
        decryptdata=new String(cipherDat);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return decryptdata;
}
```

**Main Class**

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String odata = "abcd";
    String encdata2;
    String decrypt2;
    String decrypt1;
    MultilevelEnc r = new MultilevelEnc(odata);
    String encdata = r.Encrypt(); // RSA Algo Encryption        
    Helper h = new Helper("");
    encdata2 = h.encrypt(encdata);  // 3Des Algo Encryption

    decrypt2 = h.decrypt(encdata2); // 3Des Decryption
    decrypt1 = r.Decrypt(decrypt2);  // RSA Decryption
}
```

Comment: You're going to need to provide more implementation info than that to figure things out. For all we know `MultilevelEnc#Decrypt()` could be anywhere from an `O(n!)` to an `O(n)` implementation...

Comment: However, you can *estimate* the time complexity be feeding in inputs of varying lengths and measure the time taken to process the input.

Comment: What do you mean by "time complexity" here? Are you talking about big-O notation, or wall-clock time elapsed, or both?

Comment: Both... I have to show both on paper. @templatetypedef

Comment: @user3580294 I have provided more code.. please check it

Comment: Well, now the problem is that the details of the algorithm is hidden inside the classes you use... You really can only calculate time complexity if you have access to the full algorithm, whether that is in code or if you know what implementation is used by the classes you use.

Comment: @user3580294 Yea, I know. Hence, I am confused. But if you go by normal definition of both RSA and 3Des then I have to calculate the time complexity as:
O(RSA Encryption)+O(3Des Encryption)+O(RSA Decryption)+O(3Des Decryption) right??? Or no.

Comment: I think so? I believe that operations applied successively have their big O times added, while nested operations would have them multiplied.

Comment: Looks like you have bigger problems... `cipherData = cipher.doFinal(src); srco=new String(cipherData);` does not do what you seem to think it does.  Decoding a byte stream into Java characters will destroy it for the purposes of cryptography.  There's no guarantee the reverse operation will produce the original byte stream.

Comment: Also, everything you've shown is _O(1)_ as it contains no loops.  Any complexity measures will be based on the operations you call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, all standard encryption algorithms these days work by applying a block cipher to different pieces of the input, one after the other, after doing some quick preprocessing on each block. Each block cipher works on a fixed-size input and thus has runtime O(1) (though it may be a large O(1)), so the runtime of each of the encryption and decryption algorithms should be O(n) (O(n) blocks to process, O(1) time per block). You're running a fixed number of iterations of this cipher, so the runtime should be O(n) as well.

To get a rough estimate of the wall-clock runtime, you can use the `System.nanoTime` function to get an estimate of the current time in nanoseconds, then perform your operations, and call `System.nanoTime` again to get the current time again. The difference then gives you the total runtime.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, thank you.. I got your point..